# How to Combine columns from multiple query results in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to combine the columns resulting from running two different queries in mySQL.

[image]

Query A :

```
SELECT us.id as RecruiterID,
       concat(us.first_name," ",us.last_name) as Recruiter,
       count(aj.current_step>6) as Submissions 
FROM applied_jobs as aj 
LEFT JOIN job_postings as jp ON aj.job_posting_id=jp.id 
LEFT JOIN users as us ON aj.applied_by_id=us.id 
WHERE aj.created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE()+1 
AND aj.current_step>6
group by Recruiter
```

Query B :

```
SELECT concat(us.first_name," ",us.last_name) as Recruiter,
       COUNT(sc.applied_jobs_id) as SELECTIONS
FROM `selected_candidates` as sc 
LEFT JOIN applied_jobs as aj ON sc.applied_jobs_id=aj.id 
LEFT JOIN users as us ON aj.applied_by_id=us.id 
WHERE sc.`created_at` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE()+1
GROUP BY Recruiter
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though your question needs a bit of clarity , you could use `UNION ALL` and in an outer query do the select and add aggregate function `SUM` in your case grouping by  `Recruiter`. Note that I added `null as selections` and `null as submissions`.

Try:

```
select t1.Recruiter,
       sum(t1.Submissions) as submissions,
       sum(t1.selections) as selections
from ( 

         SELECT 
                concat(us.first_name," ",us.last_name) as Recruiter,
                count(aj.current_step>6) as submissions,
                null as selections     
         FROM applied_jobs as aj 
         LEFT JOIN job_postings as jp ON aj.job_posting_id=jp.id 
         LEFT JOIN users as us ON aj.applied_by_id=us.id 
         WHERE aj.created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE()+1 
         AND aj.current_step>6
         group by Recruiter
         
         union all 
         
         SELECT concat(us.first_name," ",us.last_name) as Recruiter,
                null as submissions,
                COUNT(sc.applied_jobs_id) as selections
         FROM `selected_candidates` as sc 
         LEFT JOIN applied_jobs as aj ON sc.applied_jobs_id=aj.id 
         LEFT JOIN users as us ON aj.applied_by_id=us.id 
         WHERE sc.`created_at` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE()+1
         GROUP BY Recruiter
        
    ) as t1
group by t1.Recruiter;
```